# How to refer to the theme item instance from within an action method in StateMachine?

Tags: codenameone

Right now,

i am casting it down to its type. If I use it in an `ActionListener`, I'm declaring it as final:

```
final TextField tf = ((TextField)c); 
tf = tf.getText();
```

Here,

```
Component c
```

is the parameter of the action method.

There doesn't seem to be a method in `Component` or in anyone of the descendants returning the component instance. The name of the component in Designer interface didn't work either.

One other i can think of is using `ActionEvent.getSource()`. I haven't tried it yet-- there should be a more direct way(?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
TextField t = findNameOfMyTextField(c);
```

Comment: Not recognizing it. which class is it defined in?

Comment: StatemachineBase, these methods are automatically generated when you save the resource file. I suggest going thru the How Do I videos on the website specifically http://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---handle-eventsnavigation-in-the-gui-builder--populate-the-form-from-code.html